# Single-page vs multi-page web apps?

Tags: javascript, html

What are the pros and cons? (and dont say single page is slower at loading! it's not if done right)

Comment: Actually there is no real disadvantage in using single-page webapps IMO (i'd happily go for them in most cases) with bookmarkable hash-urls and intelligent lazy loading techniques. A single page web-app can surely give the user a much better app-like usability experience (as you said, if done well)

Comment: I dont think this question should have been closed.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/single-or-multi-page-web-application some similar question :) we can collaborate there